# Constant path replacement for different environments using gradle

Tags: java, gradle

This is a Apache Storm based project. I have a Constants file which looks something like this

```
public class Constant {    
    public static final String CONTEXT_PATH ="<some path to a context.xml file>"; 
    public static final String APP_PROPERTIES_PATH = "<path to the properties file>";

    //...More static properties
}
```

This CONTEXT_PATH variable is different for different environments (dev, test, prod).

I have a gradle task which generates the JAR file for deployment

```
task stormJar(type: Jar) {
    baseName = 'diagnostic'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

I was looking to dynamically change or refer the CONTEXT_PATH variable so that we can create builds for different environments without making any changes to this file.

I believe there are solutions to do so in the Android territory (BuildConfig), but not able to find a solution for a plain Java project.

The solution should be such, it should work for IDE (IntelliJ and Eclipse) as well as create environment specific build.

Doing something like below should get the work done

```
gradlew build -pEnvironment=prod
```

Not much experience with gradle. Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note there is a working example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_64578015).

One technique is to generate `Constants.java` as part of the build. Consider this template (stored as a resource, not as Java code):

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String CONTEXT_PATH = "__CONTEXT_PATH";
    public static final String APP_PROPERTIES_PATH = "__APP_PROPERTIES_PATH";
}
```

and the following generates `Constants.java` early in the `compileJava` task:

```
compileJava.doFirst {
    def newConstantsFile = new File("${projectDir}/src/main/java/net/codetojoy/util/Constants.java")
    def templateConstantsFile = new File("${projectDir}/resources/TemplateConstants.java")

    newConstantsFile.withWriter { def writer ->
        templateConstantsFile.eachLine { def line ->
            def newLine = line.replace("__PACKAGE", "net.codetojoy.util")
                              .replace("__CONTEXT_PATH", getContextPath())
                              .replace("__APP_PROPERTIES_PATH", getAppPropertiesPath())
            writer.write(newLine + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

and then the crucial env-specific predicates:

```
def getContextPath = { ->
    def result = "default"

    if (project.Environment == "prod") {
        result = "PROD context path here"
    } else if (project.Environment == "uat") {
        result = "UAT context path here"
    } else if (project.Environment == "dev") {
        result = "DEV context path here"
    }

    return result
}

def getAppPropertiesPath = { ->
    def result = "default"

    if (project.Environment == "prod") {
        result = "PROD app properties path here"
    } else if (project.Environment == "uat") {
        result = "UAT app properties path here"
    } else if (project.Environment == "dev") {
        result = "DEV app properties path here"
    }

    return result
}
```

Note that the ENV-specific values could easily be abstracted into config files, ENV vars, etc.

Also note that the example addresses: Java `package` used, project version, and build timestamp as well. I write something like this for most projects.